# wordpress. How to create approving of new users?

Tags: php, wordpress, registration

I want to allow users to login only after registration, approved by site admin.
Steps, that i see:
- user register, not logged-in
- user receive email with info about waiting for moderation
- admin receive email with new user info
- admin go to wp-admin and approve or decline new user
- user receive email with info about approve or decline

How to realize this?

Answer (score 1):

try one of this plugins:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-approve-user/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/new-user-approve/

Answer (score 0):

you can use a new field such as "status" in the database where you store the details of the members waiting for approval..by default set it to not permitted.when the admin checks the new request he can accept it by changing the status to permitted..and on the login page create an if else loop and only if status is permitted the users can log in..till then they will have to wait..
about sending the information via email..i am still trying to figure it out..
Hope this helps..:)